# ncurses printing to screen from mysql

Tags: mysql, c, ncurses

Sorry I am new to the c api for mysql, and I am simply trying to use the selected output of my query as a character to be printed to my ncurses window.

I am trying this:

```
mysql_query(conn, "SELECT 10 as x, 10 as y, 'x' as ch");
result = mysql_use_result(conn);
row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
move(atoi(row[1]),atoi(row[0]));
addch((char)(int)(intptr_t)row[2]); //<-- built from random suggestions on the internets
```

This (finally) successfully moves my cursor to the 10,10 position on the screen, however it prints

```
^G
```

I have also tried

```
printw("%.*s", row[2])
```

which prints

```
(null)
```

But clearly row[2] is not null. It should be 'x'.

Please I ask you, What Am I Missing??

Comment: Try the printing example from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-row.html to check the return from your query.  Also, I think that type of print (w/ the `.*s`) requires a length variable as well.  A similar print is in the linked example.

Comment: For reference re: the asterisk (\*) in printf, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string, specifically the line: "The width and precision formatting parameters may be omitted, or they can be a fixed number embedded in the format string, or passed as another function argument when indicated by an asterisk "*" in the format string. For example printf("%*d", 5, 10) will result in "   10" being printed, with a total width of 5 characters, and printf("%.*s", 3, "abcdef") will result in "abc" being printed."